# inserting multiple entry in one table with join entry in one table

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have a person table and destination table in my project i am adding a person on the table and also adding his destination in another table.He can have multiple destination. My question is how best to add the destination of that person

My table looks like this

### person_tbl

sys_id

f_name

l_name

age

gender

### destination_tbl

sys_id

person_id

continent

country

city

How best to do this kind of inserting in database i am using php pdo i only tried saving one but i am not sure how to deal with multiple entry like this one

`UPDATE`

for now i am only able to save one entry meaning i am saving using the input text field. I will change it after fill up of input text boxes i will need to put the value in a table from there when there are multiple destination it will add value to table then i will get the value of the entry in table then save it in database. THe next step is cloudy for me i am not sure what is the best approach to save many destination of one person is it best to save each destination or that person?any ideas is a great help

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you are asking for. Just execute two SQL insert statements and your data is inserted to the database. You might want to clarify the question a bit and include the steps you already perform in your code.

Comment: @MarkusMüller i updated

Comment: Ok, you need to post all the entered data to your backend. You can use the array syntax on field names in your HTML and PHP will transform it to arrays. Then just loop through these arrays and insert the destinations one at a time.